# Meteor add accounts-password -> npm error

Tags: javascript, npm, meteor

```
alexyorke@alexyorke-System-Product-Name:~/Документы/SchoolProject/myapp$ meteor add accounts-password
 => Errors while adding packages:             

While loading package npm-bcrypt@0.7.7:
error: Command failed:
/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm
rebuild --update-binary
../src/bcrypt_node.cc: In destructor ‘virtual
{anonymous}::baton_base::~baton_base()’:
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:118:18: error: ‘class v8::Persistent<v8::Function>’ has
no member named ‘Dispose’
callback.Dispose();
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc: At global scope:
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:202:19: error: variable or field ‘GenSaltAsync’ declared
void
void GenSaltAsync(uv_work_t* req) {
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:202:19: error: ‘uv_work_t’ was not declared in this scope
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:202:30: error: ‘req’ was not declared in this scope
void GenSaltAsync(uv_work_t* req) {
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:487:30: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
NODE_MODULE(bcrypt_lib, init);
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:85:13: warning: ‘void crypto_lock_init()’ defined but not
used [-Wunused-function]
static void crypto_lock_init(void) {
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:95:13: warning: ‘void crypto_lock_cb(int, int, const
char*, int)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
static void crypto_lock_cb(int mode, int n, const char* file, int line)
{
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:105:22: warning: ‘long unsigned int crypto_id_cb()’
defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
static unsigned long crypto_id_cb(void) {
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:144:5: warning: ‘int {anonymous}::GetSeed(uint8_t*, int)’
defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
int GetSeed(uint8_t* seed, int size) {
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:154:6: warning: ‘bool {anonymous}::ValidateSalt(const
char*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
bool ValidateSalt(const char* salt) {
^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Ошибка 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
(/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
(internal/child_process.js:211:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-47-generic
gyp ERR! command
"/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
"rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd
/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt/.0.7.7.1w2d5g8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/.temp-19pny6l/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-47-generic
npm ERR! argv
"/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"rebuild" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.6.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!
/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt/.0.7.7.1w2d5g8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/.temp-19pny6l/npm-debug.log
../src/bcrypt_node.cc: In destructor ‘virtual
{anonymous}::baton_base::~baton_base()’:
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:118:18: error: ‘class v8::Persistent<v8::Function>’ has
no member named ‘Dispose’
callback.Dispose();
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc: At global scope:
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:202:19: error: variable or field ‘GenSaltAsync’ declared
void
void GenSaltAsync(uv_work_t* req) {
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:202:19: error: ‘uv_work_t’ was not declared in this scope
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:202:30: error: ‘req’ was not declared in this scope
void GenSaltAsync(uv_work_t* req) {
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:487:30: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
NODE_MODULE(bcrypt_lib, init);
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:85:13: warning: ‘void crypto_lock_init()’ defined but not
used [-Wunused-function]
static void crypto_lock_init(void) {
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:95:13: warning: ‘void crypto_lock_cb(int, int, const
char*, int)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
static void crypto_lock_cb(int mode, int n, const char* file, int line)
{
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:105:22: warning: ‘long unsigned int crypto_id_cb()’
defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
static unsigned long crypto_id_cb(void) {
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:144:5: warning: ‘int {anonymous}::GetSeed(uint8_t*, int)’
defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
int GetSeed(uint8_t* seed, int size) {
^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:154:6: warning: ‘bool {anonymous}::ValidateSalt(const
char*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
bool ValidateSalt(const char* salt) {
^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Ошибка 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
(/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
(internal/child_process.js:211:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-47-generic
gyp ERR! command
"/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
"rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd
/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt/.0.7.7.1w2d5g8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/.temp-19pny6l/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-47-generic
npm ERR! argv
"/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"rebuild" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.6.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!
/home/alexyorke/.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt/.0.7.7.1w2d5g8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/.temp-19pny6l/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed

Попробуй разобраться с этим и поиграйся с версиями пакета bcrypt. А вообще, почитай повнимательнее вывод ошибки, наверняка что-то да окажется значимым. Попробуй вообще без bcrypt.

Comment: Предложения лучше писать в комментарии. Предпологается, что ответ - это ответ :)

Comment: Так это и есть ответ ;)